# Is there a way to make Crystal Reports include a constant in a join condition, without using a SQL command object?

Tags: crystal-reports

What I want to do is an outer join to a table, where I exclude records from the joined table based on matching a constant, however keep records from the main table. For example:

```
SELECT a.id, a.other, b.baz
FROM a
LEFT OUTER JOIN b
  ON a.id  = b.id
  AND b.bar = 'foo'
```

Expected results:

```
    id  other       baz      
    --  ----------  -------  
    1   Has foo     Include  
    2   Has none    (null)   
    3   Has foobar  (null)
```

I can't get the same results by putting it in the filter condition. If I use the following:

```
SELECT a.id, a.other, b.baz
FROM a
LEFT OUTER JOIN b
  ON a.id  = b.id
WHERE (b.bar IS NULL OR b.bar = 'foo')
```

I get these incorrect results:

```
    id  other     baz      
    --  --------  -------  
    1   Has foo   Include  
    2   Has none  (null)
```

Where it excluded records of A that happen to match a record of B where bar = 'foobar'. I don't want that, I want A to be present, but B to be nulls in that case.

Table B will have multiple records that need excluding, so I don't think I can filter this on the Crystal side without doing a lot of messing around to avoid problems from duplicate records from table A.

I cannot use a SQL command object, as the third party application that we are running the reports from seems to choke on SQL command objects.

I cannot use views, as our support contract does not permit database modifications, and our vendor considers adding views a database modification.

I am working with Crystal Reports XI, specifically version 11.0.0.895. In case it makes a difference, I am running against a Progress 9.1E04 database using the SQL-92 ODBC driver.

The sample tables and data used in the examples can be created with the following:

```
CREATE TABLE a (id INTEGER, other VARCHAR(32));
CREATE TABLE b (id INTEGER, bar VARCHAR(32), baz VARCHAR(32));
insert into A (id, other) values ('1', 'Has foo');
insert into A (id, other) values ('2', 'Has none');
insert into A (id, other) values ('3', 'Has foobar');
insert into B (id, bar, baz) values ('1', 'foo', 'Include');
insert into B (id, bar, baz) values ('1', 'foobar', 'Exclude');
insert into B (id, bar, baz) values ('1', 'another', 'Exclude');
insert into B (id, bar, baz) values ('1', 'More', 'Exclude');
insert into B (id, bar, baz) values ('3', 'foobar', 'Exclude');
```

Comment: Could you define the structure of table, current result, expected result?

Comment: +1 - Good question and fun exercise. I played with this for a little bit to see if I could figure out a solution without using the Crystal Reports SQL Command since you said it wouldn't work for you, but I couldn't come up with an easy way outside of some hacky grouping and suppression logic. You can get what you need in a roundabout way, but I don't think it's the solution you're looking for. Sorry man/mam.

Answer (score 9):

Crystal reports can't generate that commonly used SQL statement based on its links and report selection criteria.  You have to use a "command" or build a view.

In short, Crystal sucks.

Answer (score 2):

Is a stored procedure an option for you? If so you could pre-select the data sets that way without having to resort to the command option, and one can import a stored procedure as one would a table.

I would propose stored procedure which does `select * from b where bar= 'foo'` and join to that, such that the b table is pre-filtered so all you have to do is join on the other join field.

Hope that helps.

Comment: "our support contract does not permit database modifications" stored procedures are also considered database modifications.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if you can do this in Crystal but how about joining to a Select?

```
SELECT a.id, x.baz
FROM a
LEFT OUTER JOIN 
 (SELECT id, baz FROM b WHERE bar = 'foo') As x ON a.id  = x.id
```

Comment: I don't know any way to do that in Crystal without a command object. If someone can tell me how, I would be very grateful as that would solve other problems too.

Answer (score 0):

Can't you create appropriate views in database and base your report on these views? I'm using Crystal Reports on MSSQL and often I just create views to avoid similar problems.

Comment: Our vendor considers adding views as a violation of our support contract. I think that's stupid, but we've been unable to convince the vendor otherwise.

Comment: You should probably consider finding an alternate vendor as this vendor does seem pretty bloody hopeless.

Comment: I agree, but I'm not the one with the authority to choose. Since the application is a fairly market specific vertical that we just spent 5 years putting in and having them make customizations for us, it is very unlikely we will be able to convince the business to switch in the near future.

Answer (score 0):

I can see two solutions:

a) accept presence of multiple (unneeded) rows in B (and repeated values in A), calculate totals using runnign total fields and/or formulas - not easy way, but almost always possible;
b) move B into subreport (where you can set filter easily) and communicate needed values between main and subreport using shared variables.

Subreports are powerful tool for solving this kind of problems, unless you need to nest them (not possible) or export reports into excel (adds empty lines, at least in CR 9).

Answer (score 0):

Adding

```
(Isnull({b.bar}) OR {b.bar} = "foo")
```

to the record-selection formula should act as you expect.

** edit **

A couple of other things to try:

- Use a different database driver--the native driver (that avoids ODBC) may act differently.  I first noticed this using the WITH syntax--the SQL Server ODBC driver didn't work, but the SQL Server native driver did.
- While it sacrifices some flexibility, embed the query in a Command, assuming you can get the 3rd-party's product to comply.  Added for completeness.

Comment: Oh really? Will record 3 in the above example be included? That looks the same as the query I already tried and listed in the question as not producing the correct answer.

Comment: you must have tried it in the command.  this should work in the record-selection formula.  i've had similar issues in the past (where i wanted to add the filter in the JOIN clause) and had to resolve it this way.  you should try it before you cast aspersions.

Comment: Wow craig, going for the necromancer badge huh? :). Sorry, but I tried this and it works the same as if the criteria is in the where clause in the query therefore only showing id 1 and 2.

Comment: Haha, agreed. On your update, the command is definitely the way to go, but it sounds like that wasn't an option in 2008 when the question was originally asked, but maybe the client would be less strict now. +1 for the effort.

Answer (score 0):

Seems to me you don't want to accept anyone's suggestions but here's one last-ditch shot at it anyway. The solution I've used recently where the db has to remain intact is as follows:

1. Set up Tomcat server so I can run some JSP and Hibernate goodness.
2. Grab Crystal reports for eclipse
3. Build report in crystal reports designer with faked data on a local db conforming to how I'd have the data in an ideal world
4. Using java servlet pass List to each of the table aliases such that the report has the data replaced directly from POJOs. The POJOs can of course be entirely composed in the java by pulling in content from various db tables and mashing them up as you see fit, often enabling one to provide a thoroughly flattened dataset that Crystal reports is only too happy to work with.

Comment: It's not that I don't want to accept suggestions - its that they are suggesting things I already listed in the initial question as blocked by our support contract. Yours goes around Crystal Reports in yet another way we can't use, but I'm not sure it was very clear from my question. Our reports are run *inside* the vendor provided application. The users expect the report there, not in an external website. In some cases the vendor provided application is passing additional parameters we need in.

Comment: Tbh then with the restrictions in place I don't see a solution. Honestly I think your vendor sucks, and is the root of your problems. Re running inside the application, at that point you have bugger all control unless you've got access to the source code or something of that ilk and with no database control you've got no chance of getting this done (only thing I can think of from here is to have an additional db on a server outside the control of your vendor to which you publish a flattened set of data through an automated process but I'm guessing your vendor won't allow that either.

Comment: That is one class of solution our vendor *will* allow. It just tends to be overkill for an individual report. The solution they suggest is switching to an essentially proprietary solution where instead of SQL, we capture the data for the report in a module written in OpenEdge ABL, then it gets dumped to XML for Crystal to work on.

Comment: I'd not recommend XML, I've tried it myself and tbh Crystal chokes on large datasets much more readily than with java beans. Part of that I suspect is the process of validating a large xml file. Trust me when I say you really don't want to go there.
Given that you have the option of posting to an external database, yes it's hard work but honestly I think it's the best option you have left at this point, and I would recommend in the long term ditching this money-grabbing vendor who seems more concerned with extracting money from you than providing a service.

Comment: OpenEdge ABL -> XML is the vendor recommended solution for reporting that avoids the performance problems with SQL. I think it is more a matter of incompetence than malice with this vendor - they come from the OpenEdge world, and don't understand SQL well enough to know that things like allowing views doesn't have much impact on the rest of the database. Combine that with the common approach of not allowing things that might complicate support, and this is what we're stuck with. We are working on a data warehouse now, so as reports can move to that they avoid these complications.

Comment: Good luck, sounds like they're pretty majorly hopeless. Definitely don't recommend XML, anything more than about 100 records and it'll die on its arse tbh. I've come across that kind of thing before though, where if they don't understand it they ban it. I tend to kick such companies swiftly to the kerb, so good luck with the data warehouse and hope it works for you. Sorry I couldn't be more help.

Answer (score 0):

You should not add filter condition for table b by `b.bar is null or b.bar = 'foo'`, but you should also not access attributes from table b directly. You should get all attributes by a condition `if b.bar = 'foo'` through a formula.